# Trouble with passing bson objectid to numpy recarray in python 3

Tags: python, mongodb, numpy, pymongo

I am working on machine translating some text that is stored in a mongodb database. I am trying pull the data from a database and then store it in numpy recarray. However I keep getting errors when I try to save the ObjectId field to the recarray--despite the different type conversions and such I have read about. Here is my code. Any suggestions would help.

```
#Pull the records from the DB into a resultset
db_results_records_to_translate = \
        db_connector.db_fetch_untranslated_records_from_db(
        article_collection,rec_number) 

#Create an empty numpy recarray to store the data
data_table_for_translation=np.zeros([db_results_records_to_translate.count(),6],
                        dtype=[('_id', np.str),
                            ('article_raw_text', np.str),
                            ('article_raw_date', np.str),
                            ('translated',np.bool),
                            ('translated_text',np.str),
                            ('translated_date',np.str)])

#Write record data to the recarray
for index, r in enumerate(db_results_records_to_translate):
        data_table_for_translation[index, 0] = str(r['_id']) # Line with errors!!!
        data_table_for_translation[index,1] = r['article_raw_text']
        data_table_for_translation[index,2] = r['article_raw_date']
        data_table_for_translation[index, 3] = r['translated']
```

So after running this code, I get an error `TypeError: expected an object with a buffer interface.`

Now I have tried to convert the objectid from bson to string using the `str(ObjectId)` function as referenced in the documentation, but no luck.

Any suggestions?

NOTE: I noticed that this error happens even for the non-id columns too, so even straight text has an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are errors in the definition of the array, including the dtype, and errors in indexing fields during the iteration.

This is clip illustrates the changes I think you need to make to get this assignment to work:

```
# fake data - a list of tuples
db_results_records_to_translate = [('12','raw text','raw date')]

#Create an empty numpy recarray to store the data
data_table_for_translation=np.zeros([1,],
                        dtype=[('_id', 'U10'),
                               ('article_raw_text', 'U10'),
                               ('article_raw_date', 'U10')])
# string dtype has to include length
# I'm using unicode here (Python3), 'S10' would do just as well (in py2)

#Write record data to the structured array
for index, r in enumerate(db_results_records_to_translate):
   data_table_for_translation[index]['_id'] = str(r[0])
   data_table_for_translation[index]['article_raw_text'] = r[1]
   data_table_for_translation[index]['article_raw_date'] = r[2]

print(db_results_records_to_translate)
```

Note that I index the 'fields' by name, not number.  `data_table...` is a 1d array with n fields, not a 2d array with n columns.  I'm indexing `r` by number because my mock data is a tuple, not the db named fields.

Comment: Oh this is great. Yes, thanks so much. I have not really used recarrays before, so thanks for the corrections. I used the `object` datatype since the strings differ in lengths. Thanks again.